# Object Detection Django Rest API Deployment on Google Cloud Platform or Google ML Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, object-detection

I have developed Django API which accepts images from livefeed camera using in the form of base64 as request. Then, In API this image is converted into numpy arrays to pass to machine learning model i.e object detection using tensorflow object API. Response is simple text of detected objects.

I need GPU based cloud instance where i can deploy this application for fast processing to achieve real time results. I have searched a lot but no such resource found. I believe google cloud console (instances) can be connected to live API but I am not sure how exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using GPU locally or wherever your Django application is hosted.

First thing is to make sure that you are using `tensorflow-gpu` and all the necessary setup for `Cuda` is done.

You can start your GPU instance easily on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). There are multiple ways to do this.

#### Quick option

- Search for `notebooks` and start a new instance with the required GPU and
  RAM.
- Instead of the notebook instance, you can set up the instance separately if you need some specific OS and more flexibility on choosing the machine.
- To access the instance with `ssh` simply add your ssh public key
  to Metadata which can be seen when you open the instance details.
- Setup Django as you would do on the server. To test it simply just debug run it on host `0` or `0.0.0.0` and preferred port.
- You can access the APIs with the external IP of the machine which can be found out in the instance details page.

#### Some suggestions

- While the first option is quick and dirty, it's not recommended to use that in production.
- It is better to use some deployment services such as `tensorflow-serving` along with Kubeflow.
- If you think that you're handling the inference properly itself, then make sure that you load balance the server properly. Use NGINX or any other good server along with gunicorn/uwsgi.
- You can use redis for queue management. When someone calls the API, it is not necessary that GPU is available for the inference. It is fine not to use this when you have very less number of hits on the API per second. But when we think of scaling up, think of 50 requests per second which a single GPU can't handle at a time, we can use a queue system.
- All the requests should directly go to redis first and the GPU takes the jobs required to be done from the queue. If required, you can always scale the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud actually offers Cloud GPUs. If you are looking to perform higher level computations with your applications that require real-time capabilities I would suggest your look into the following link for more information. 
https://cloud.google.com/gpu/

Compute Engine also provides GPUs that can be added to your virtual machine instances. Use GPUs to accelerate specific workloads on your instances such as Machine Learning and data processing.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/

However, if your application requires a lot of resources you’ll need to increase your quota to ensure you have enough GPUs available in your project. Make sure to pick a zone where GPUs are available. If this requires much more computing power you would need to submit a request for an increase of your quota. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#create-new-gpu-instance

Since you would be using the Tensorflow API for your application on ML Engine I would advise you to take a look at this link below. It provides instructions for creating a Deep Learning VM instance with TensorFlow and other tools pre-installed.
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/tensorflow_start_instance